# Pyspark Handle Ctrl + Z?

Tags: apache-spark, signals, pyspark

When running pyspark, if you do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in the middle of a process, it stops the job from running but does not close SparkContext. This means the port is not closed either and spark has to jump through several ports to connect the next time someone runs a spark job. I want to prevent people from using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> while running these scripts, but the standard python handler doesn't seem to work when SparkContext is running, which I assume is a result of the fact that it's technically running in java and I've only set a handler for python? Here is a sample of what I've written.

```
    import signal
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    sc = SparkContext()

    def handler(signum, frame):
        print 'Please refrain from using CTRL + Z, use CTRL + C instead'

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)

    while True:
        pass
```

When I run this code, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> still does the default behavior of pausing rather than executing my handler function.

This code does work the way I want it to if I eliminate the spark content as so:

```
    import signal

    def handler(signum, frame):
        print 'Please refrain from using CTRL + Z, use CTRL + C instead'

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, handler)

    while True:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding `trap "" SIGTSTP` to my spark-submit shell script just before the spark-submit.